# How to restore the color theme of terminal in Elementary OS?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

Some time ago, I used the Gogh to change the color themes of the Terminal. But now I want to reset or restore the default color theme, but don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to click in the "gear" icon located in the top-right portion of the window and change it from there?

Comment: No. The "gear" allows 3 color modes, but each of them will only change the background color instead of the entire syntax theme. Thanks.

Comment: I think that info is in you .bashrc file (/home/username/.bashrc). Try renaming that file, logoff and back in and see if that color scheme was re-set.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can check [this link](https://gist.github.com/davidgomes/5162998). It has extra info about it but check my other comment as well. :)